# Is there a way to make jqGrid scroll to the bottom when a new row is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on a page and users can click a button to add a new row.  If there are already enough rows on the page to fill the visible portion of the grid the new row is added and a scroll bar appears but the user needs to scroll to see the new row.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do this using the jqGrid API is to:

- Call `editRow` (which will set focus to the edited row)
- And then immediately call `restoreRow` (because you do not really want to edit the row)

<del>Otherwise you should be able to use jQuery's `focus` function to set focus to the row, for example: `jQuery("#" + row_id).focus()` - but I have not tested this method, so YMMV.</del>

Actually `focus` will not scroll the grid's div. But you can use the following code to guarantee that the grid scrolls such that the row with a given `id` is viewable:

```
function getGridRowHeight (targetGrid) {
    var height = null; // Default

    try{
        height = jQuery(targetGrid).find('tbody').find('tr:first').outerHeight();
    }
    catch(e){
     //catch and just suppress error
    }

    return height;
}

function scrollToRow (targetGrid, id) {
    var rowHeight = getGridRowHeight(targetGrid) || 23; // Default height
    var index = jQuery(targetGrid).getInd(id);
    jQuery(targetGrid).closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(rowHeight * index);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I do want to edit the row so I'll just leave it in edit mode - works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks Justin! the only modification that i should do is .scrollTop( (rowHeight * index)-rowHeight) to make viewable the target row. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
//i. Set newly added row (with id = newRowId) as the currently selected row
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('setSelection', newRowId);
//ii. Set focus on the currently selected row
$("#" + $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')).focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI:

I found this example helpful. http://gurarie.org/jqGrid.html from this post, http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/setselection-is-not-scrolling-to-the-selected-row

My issue was `$(tableInstance).jqGrid('setSelection', id)` didn't work even `scrollrows: true` when `height: 'auto'` in jqGrid config. I set height to a specific height 20 and 'setSelection' worked. The selected row was in view for the user. Super Cool